# How do I fix: node command not found? (VSCODE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to load two js files to another js file and I used jquery using CDN.

This is my code for the heading in html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this is the code for the first js file:

```
const countries = ["Philippines", "Australia", "Italy", "Norway", "Japan", "Israel"]
```

this is the code for the second js file:

```
const webTechs = ['Javascript', 'Python', 'SQL', 'Go', 'Native']
```

the code in script (I'm loading the country(js) file first):

```
 $.getScript("country.js", function() {
    console.log(countries)
});
```

yet when i try to load the two external files, first in tech(j)s file it says:

```
     const webTechs = ['Javascript', 'Python', 'SQL', 'Go', 'Native']
    /bin/sh: line 1: node: command not found
```

I'd appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: unclear what node has to do with clientside javascript

Comment: How, exactly, are you trying to load the two external files?  What commands are you typing?

Comment: @TimRoberts using jquery